# Regular expression to find @Razor references in HTML

Tags: c#, html, regex

I have some text resources that contain HTML and @Razor markup. They are fed through a razor engine, so references like @Model.FirstName are replaced with the appropriate value. Also, the razor references are in HTML tag contents as well as attributes of the HTML.

e.g.
`<a href="my/example/url?param=@Model.TheParam">Hello @Model.FirstName, I believe your surname is @Model.Surname.</a>`

In this instance I want a regular expression to detect `@Model.FirstName` and `@Model.Surname`, but ignore the text between them, and also ignore the `@Model.TheParam`, because it is within the HTML attribute.

The regex I have managed so far is `@?Model.[a-zA-Z]*`, which matches all 3 model+parameter pairs, but I only want the last 2.

[freeformatter.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmsDR.png)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the desired output given the provided input.

Comment: Show what have you done to solve you problem, and then we help you according to your hitches

Comment: Why don't you use the *razor* engine for this, and pass a Model object instead of replacing those references? Which razor engine are you using?

Comment: I have to feed the whole thing through AWS translation, which helpfuly ignores the tag itself, but translates the contents into @Model. 名字, which breaks the later razor rendering. I don't know which razor engine is in use.

Answer (score 0):

> (?<=>.*)@\s*Model.[a-zA-Z]*

```
 try this
```